# Automating Terminal and Mainframe in Blue Prism

Tags: terminal, element, rpa, blueprism

I'm working on a robot that will work on a 5250 terminal IBM Mainframe.

Using application modeller I am able to identify specific fields that needs to be filed whit text(userId) numbers(function number) but I cant accept those values by pressing an "Enter".

How can I send in key to Terminal via Blue Prism??? When I'm using an action step in Object Studio, all I can do whit identified elements is "verify" them.

Comment: OK, I found it. When you conect Blue Prism to a mainframe, to send a key to it, you need to use Navigate. In Navigate dont use any Elements from your Application Modeller but you need to use a main element - top of your element tree. Then you will be able to sand in key like ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to use Navigate Stage. Action will be "Global Send keys". 
The text is "[ENTER]".

If you want to use Function 1-12, then you have to use Text: "[pf1-12]".